# Sql, Object vs String/Array

Tags: php, sql

Why does this produce an object?

```
$sql = $this->db->query("
  SELECT 'product_id'
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category
  WHERE category_id = '" . $this->db->escape($category['category_id']) . "'
");
```

And how to I get a string/array instead?

From Opencart
Related: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: According to usage and table name it is class from `OpenCart`.

Comment: Yeah it's Opencart, I think they used CodeIgniter to build it. What other info will be helpful?

Comment: @Cleverbot, see /admin/models/country.php - there are a lot of good examples about working with `db` layer. Also, there a lot of examples in other model files. PS: Don't forget to escape string data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your query syntax, you put SELECT 'product_id' and you should not have apostrophies there.

```
$sql = $this->db->query("
  SELECT 'product_id'
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category
  WHERE category_id = '" . $this->db->escape($category['category_id']) . "'
");
```

You need to make this change.

```
$sql = $this->db->query("
  SELECT product_id
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category
  WHERE category_id = '" . $this->db->escape($category['category_id']) . "'
");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming CodeIgniter:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

```
$this->db->query();
```

> The query() function returns a database result **object** when "read" type
>   queries are run, which you can use to show your results.

You can process the result set rows as array, using `result_array`:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

Comment: I get "Call to undefined method stdClass::result_array()". It's totally bizarre I'm not getting a string/array like it normally does.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = $this->db->query("
  SELECT 'product_id'
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category
  WHERE category_id = '" . $this->db->escape($category['category_id']) . "'
");
$rows = $sql->rows; //array of all returned values
$row = $sql->row; //first row
```

I highly recommend you to use `var_dump($sql)` to investigate what public object fields could be useful for you.

*Fixed syntax

Comment: That totally turned it into an array thanks!! One other thing, what if my return is a single string? should I cut out "$rows = #sql->$rows;"?

Comment: `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "country"); return $query->row['total'];` Note `$query->row`, not `$query->rows`.

Comment: That works but I was looking to extract a single string value from the database, or a single string value from the array from the database. When I try your initial method it just gives me the name of the value as opposed to the value itself.

Comment: This is my dump: 'Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => product_id
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => product_id
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => product_id
        )

)'